# Redirección de una IP

Tags: ip

Es posible que una dirección ip redireccione a otra?

Quiero decir, yo tengo una IP (la importante) por ejemplo 1.2.3.4 y quiero que al conectarme a la IP (nueva) por ejemplo 1.1.2.2 esta me lleve a la 1.2.3.4

Sería posible? Cómo? Gracias!

Comment: Buenas, bienvenido a stackoverflow en español.Deberias indicar en que lenguaje quieres realizar esa redireccion y que has intentado sin poder resolverlo... sino nadie podra ayudarte... saludos

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que hablas cuando te conectas a un servidor web tuyo. Si es así, lo puedes hacer con la **redirección 301**.

Se hará de forma diferente si el servidor es de windows o linux, además de la versión del servidor web que utilices, por ejemplo:

**En windows**, echa un vistazo a: https://www.blizzarddigital.com/blog/301-redirect-iis/

**En Linux:** [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299241/redirecci%c3%b3n-de-una-ip](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299241/redirecci%C3%B3n-de-una-ip)

La otra opción es que las IP´s apunten a un nombre de dominio, esto haría que simplemente lo cambiases con las DNS. Incluso podrías utilizar Cloudflare dns.